# VBA code to copy and paste daily changing .csv file into excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv

So I have a .csv file that gets exported everyday into my files, of the format: "FILENAME03_28_2017-14_45_01" so it changes everyday with the date. I am trying to be able to copy and paste everything from that file into a different excel sheet, but since the file name changes everyday I can't figure out how to write the code to maybe look at a certain cell for the date and concatenate that with the basic FILENAME to open it. I have a code that opens up the latest file in that folder, but its the copy paste part i'm stuck at.

you can't just do something like (where C15 contains the current date)??

```
Windows("C:\Users\ME\Desktop\FOLDERS\FILENAME" & Range("C15")&".csv").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("EXCELFILE.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("SHEET1").Select
Range("T1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste`
```

thank you!

Comment: what is the line with the problem, is it ActiveSheet.Paste?

Comment: no, the issue is with the first line, not sure how to make it dynamic so that it opens the file with the new date every day

Comment: The answer of Yoav24 is not ok? He gave you a function you can use to capture the actual date. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: where do i put that in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this vba code to capture the date:

```
format(date, "mm_dd_yyyy") 'returns "03_28_2017"
```

*Date* is a keyword in Excel VBA that gives today's date in mm/dd/yyyy format. However, you can use that *Format* function as written above to cast it into many formats. The resulting output is a string, not a date -  so you can use it in your dynamic filename.

Comment: if the filename has the day's date in it, you can use this function to get a string of the date. then, you can have every day's file be correctly recognized as filename_date

Comment: file path = C:\Users\ME\Desktop\FOLDERS\FILENAME + format(date, "mm_dd_yyyy")